# Appending String to UserDefault Array

Tags: swift, userdefaults

Hey guys so I know that we can append single string to userdefault but I was wondering how we can append [String: String]

So here is my code

```
 var savedArray = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "array1") as! [String]

   let name = John
   let lastname = Smith
   if let index = savedArray?.index(where: {$0 != name!}) {
    savedArray?.append(name!)
   }
   //this code works fine but now I want to add more than just name. So I tried this code below

   if let index = savedArray?.index(where: {$0 != name!}) {
    savedArray?.append(name!, lastname!)
   }
```

But then I get a error that says extra argument in call. So I am assuming that because on top I put as! [String]. But if I put

```
   var savedArray = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "array1") as! [String: String]
```

I can't append this variable because the error message says that append is not available for String: String. Is there anyway to append multiple strings into a Userdefault? When I tried to google this it only shows how to set your userdefaults to the strings but I want to keep adding values into the userdefaults.

Answer (score 1):

Just append twice:

```
savedArray?.append(name!)
savedArray?.append(lastname!)
```

Or you can use `append(contentsOf:)` with an array, but there seems no need for that here.

Comment: k so savedArray?.append(name!) was working fine yesterday. Now its just printing nil everytime...

Answer (score 1):

You are using too many question and exclamation marks. Since `savedArray`, `name` and `lastName` are non-optional you will get a couple of compiler errors with the *optional* syntax anyway.

Rather than googling the stuff I recommend to read the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array), there are examples how to append multiple elements. And `contains` is preferable over `index` in this case:

```
if !savedArray.contains(name) {
    savedArray.append(contentsOf: [name, lastname])
}
```